# android studio is not building my app after upgrade in studio 3.0 canery7

Tags: android

My Android studio is not building my apps after upgrade in studio 3 canery 7

this also not buliding previous projects .

this is my gradle file

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }



    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
   repositories {
       jcenter()
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a build gradle version problem .
change the project level build file

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
```

to

```
 dependencies {
        //  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
       }
```

and add repositories

```
repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
```

final your build file like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      //  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6'
     }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this: On your build gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```